# CasperJS: how to pass arguments and use them in a loop

Tags: loops, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm working on a script and I need to pass some arguments, the way I'm passing the arguments is like this:

```
xvfb-run casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any casper/server.js --checks='["215","216"]'
```

Inside the server.js I assign it to a variable:

```
var checks = casper.cli.get('checks');
```

Then below in the code I use the code in a loop:

```
casper.each(checks, function(check) {
 $('*[data-queue="'+ check+'"] input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

My issue is that although I do **console.log(checks)** to confirm that the arguments are being received the script keeps complaining with:

```
[error] [phantom] each() only works with arrays
```

Not only that but the loop doesn't work either if I hardcode the array manually.

Comment: Hi Mario, have tried to JSON.parse the populated checks variable? Just wondering.

Comment: Yes @Luca, I tried both `JSON.stringify();` and `JSON.parse();`, same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[casper.each](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#each) callback takes TWO arguments, the first is the Casper module itself, the second is the iterated variable.

```
casper.each(checks, function(self, check) {
    // ...
});
```

If you want to manipulate the HTML page then it has to be done in the page's context, inside of `page.evaluate`:

```
casper.each(checks, function(self, check) {
    self.evaluate(function(check){
        $('*[data-queue="'+ check+'"] input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }, check);
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry, didn't notice the CLI argument of `--checks='["215","216"]'`
Of course it's not an array:

```
console.log( checks );
console.log( typeof(checks) );
```

*(notice the quotation marks '  ')*

> '[215,216]'
>   string

But if you use it like this: `--checks=["215","216"]`
and in the script:

```
console.log( typeof(eval(checks)) );
console.log( eval(checks)[1] );
```

> object
>   216

(of cource `eval` is evil and all, so it's better to change format of incoming IDs)

`casperjs casper/server.js --checks=215,216,15942,5435`

```
console.log( typeof(checks.split(",")) );
console.log( JSON.stringify(checks.split(",")) );
```

> object
>   ["215","216","15942","5435"]

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion @Vaviloff, I'm still getting the same `[error] [phantom] each() only works with arrays`, Any other ideas?

Comment: You were right, the array formatting was wrong so I was able to fix that. Also to fix the loop issue I learned that no matter what the each function needs to be evaluated first and the whole thing needs to be wrapped inside a `casper.then();` function. Thank you for the help ;)